# Why does "find / -name '*.txt' | cp /junk" not work?

Tags: find, pipe, cp, xargs

If I want to find any files with .txt in the name, and for every match that is found copy it into the /junk folder the following could be considered to work;

```
find / -name "*.txt" | cp /junk
```

but this will not work because find will produce the results as a list, which can’t be fed into cp.

So I could use xargs to resolve this

```
find / -name "*.txt" | xargs cp /junk
```

Because xargs will change the list into one line which can be fed into cp. I also think that this command would completely finish searching through the files, 'produce the list', and only then would it run the right side of the pipe (the copy).

Alternatively (and preferably) I could use exec

```
find / -name ".txt" -exec cp {} /junk \;
```

Which would run the copy each time that a match is found, (and it would run the copy in a separate process, so the find command would continue running in parallel).

Can someone confirm that these commands and my understanding is correct?

I should add that this is for education purposes only, this is not a real life scenario.

Comment: One big warning...  Your `find / `-command will include the **/junk** directory, so files already copied will be copied again.  Also, it's probably a good idea to add `-i` or `--backup=numbered` to the `cp`-command.

Comment: I see, thanks, very interesting point. This is only the case for the third command though correct? Because the second command (providing that I run it only once) would only copy once the find is fully complete?

Comment: No `xargs` might decide to run the command several times and also before the pipe is finished. Try `while sleep 1; do echo foo; done | xargs -n 3`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, `find / -name "*.txt" | cp /junk` will not work because `cp` does not read its arguments from stdin.
2. No, `find / -name "*.txt" | xargs cp /junk` will also not work because `xargs` will append the arguments it reads from stdin to the command, so `cp` would try to copy in the wrong direction. (You can try to fix that with the `-I` option to `xargs` but then you can simply use `find -exec`.)
3. Yes, `find / -name ".txt" -exec cp {} /junk \;` will work but will use one invocation of `cp` for each file (and will start that command as soon as the file is found).

You can also try this solution, I should start only one invocation of `cp` (or at least it will start as few as possible, command line length is limited):

```
find / -path /junk -prune -or -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'cp "$@" /junk'
```

As @don_chrissti commented you can use `cp -t` if you have GNU cp. It then can be done like this

```
find / -path /junk -prune -or -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /junk
```

or even

```
find / -path /junk -prune -or -name '*.txt' -exec cp -t /junk {} +
```

All three will collect as many arguments as fit on the command line and execute as few instances of `cp` as possible. But it might still be the case that a `cp` is started before `find` is done so we have to exclude `/junk` otherwise it might find the copies.

Comment: Thank you very much Lucas :) 

I am a little unclear on point 2. 

So xargs will append the output of the find command as the second argument of the cp command (cp /junk example.txt) which obviously would not work! Now you mention it, I can see that in cmd 2 cp only has one argument which is a problem that I did not see before.

Comment: I guess that `{}` also needs escaping in some shells (e.g. `fish`).